# Write a part of a cell with different color in a XLS or CSV file

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsxwriter

Is there a way to write a part of a cell in colors in a CSV or XLS file? I am using Python and for presenting my results I want to use colors to highlight a part of a cell. The cell contains texts. If there is no any way to do that with XLS, what is the best alternative?

Comment: There is no layout information in CSV files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use xlsx instead of xls/csv then you can use XlsxWriter's `write_rich_string()` method:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Set up some formats to use.
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
blue = workbook.add_format({'color': 'blue'})

worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'This is ',
                            red, 'red',
                            ' and this is ',
                            blue, 'blue')

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

See the XlsxWriter docs on [write_rich_string()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string)